# No output from loop/index exercise (Beginner Java)

Tags: java

Hey guys I'm having trouble seeing what's preventing my code below from properly compiling. I'm fairly new so I apologize in advance for my poor formatting.

```
package javaApplication2;


/*There are two players playing a card game. Both players have seven cards each.
There are seven rounds in the game. Each round, the value of the players’ cards for
that particular round are compared to see who has the highest valued card. The
player with the highest value card wins the round.
At the end of the game (after seven rounds), the program should determine which
player has won the game overall (won the most rounds) or if the game has ended in a
tie.*/

public class JavaApplication2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] wresult = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int[] lresult = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int P1round = 0, P2round = 0;
    int rounds = 0;
    String victor=null; 
    String loser=null;
    int[] winner = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int[] p1Cards = {10, 6, 8, 9, 7, 12, 7};
    int[] p2Cards = {7, 6, 9, 5, 2, 8, 11};
    int[] players = {1,2};
    boolean playing = true;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if(playing){
    //game/loop begins here
        do{

            if (p1Cards[rounds]>p2Cards[rounds]){
                winner[rounds]=players[0];
                wresult[rounds]=p1Cards[rounds];
                lresult[rounds]=p2Cards[rounds];
                P1round+=1;
                rounds++;
            }

            else if (p1Cards[rounds]<p2Cards[rounds]){
                winner[rounds]=players[1];
                wresult[rounds]=p2Cards[rounds];
                lresult[rounds]=p1Cards[rounds];
                P2round+=1;
                rounds++;}

            else wresult[rounds]=players[0];
                lresult[rounds]=players[1];
                rounds++;

        }while (rounds!=6);
        //end loop}

     //game is over
     else{playing=false;}
     if(playing==false){

     //if/else to determine the result
       if (P1round>P2round){
           victor = "Player One";
           loser = "Player Two";
       }
       else if (P2round>P1round){
           victor = "Player Two";
           loser = "Player One";
       }
       else
           System.out.println("It's a draw!");
           System.exit(0);

       System.out.println("Round No: 1- Player" + winner[0] + " wins the round:" + wresult[0] + " beats" + lresult[0]);  
       System.out.println("Round No: 2- Tie!" + wresult[1] + " ties with" + lresult[1]);
       System.out.println("Round No: 3- Player" + winner[2] + "wins the round:" + wresult[2] + " beats" + lresult[2]);
       System.out.println("Round No: 4- Player" + winner[3] + "wins the round:" + wresult[3] + " beats" + lresult[3]);
       System.out.println("Round No: 5- Player" + winner[4] + "wins the round:" + wresult[4] + " beats" + lresult[4]);
       System.out.println("Round No: 6- Player" + winner[5] + "wins the round:" + wresult[5] + " beats" + lresult[5]);
       System.out.println("Round No: 7- Player" + winner[6] + "wins the round:" + wresult[6] + " beats" + lresult[6]);
       System.out.println("Player " + victor + " wins!!!  He won " + P1round + " rounds beating " + loser + " who won " + P2round + " rounds!");
       System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please include in your question any error messages you are getting, and indicate what line(s) they occur on. Thanks.

Comment: has it occurred to you that maybe not all of the if statements you assume will evaluate to true actually evaluate to true? add print statements for every possible flow, that might show you something more

Comment: @Stultuske I think the problem is that the code doesn't compile at all, so it can't print anything yet. Correct me if I'm wrong. :)

Comment: @Keara if code doesn't compile, the compiler tends to provide an explanation for that.

Comment: The only missing brace required to make it compile is between your comments `//end loop}` and `//game is over` as you don't close the `if(playing){`.

Comment: Did any of the answers so far answer your question? If so, please consider accepting one so that other users will be able to find the information more easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are missing curly braces around two of your `else` statements. Try changing this:

```
else wresult[rounds]=players[0];
        lresult[rounds]=players[1];
        rounds++;
```

To this:

```
else { 
    wresult[rounds]=players[0];
    lresult[rounds]=players[1];
    rounds++;
}
```

Similarly, you need brackets around your final `else` statement, like this:

```
else {
       System.out.println("It's a draw!");
       System.exit(0);
}
```

If your code still doesn't compile, let me know and I can take another look.

Answer (score 0):

You run your if statement which is set to true to run the do-while loop, but the if statement where your printout is follows the condition "if(playing==false){" - playing in this scenario can never equal false.

As @Keara mentioned as well, you need to add some syntax with those curly braces.
There are some cases where the compiler will allow for you to not add curly braces such as using an if-statement with no else condition. But at the end of your while loop you have "else{playing=false;}" with no syntax precursor to it, I'd imagine you'd get an error here.

Fix your syntax and correct your print-out conditions and it should work. :)

Answer (score 0):

The only missing brace required to make it compile is between your comments `//end loop}` and `//game is over` as you don't close the `if(playing){`.

However, you should note that `playing` will never be `false` as you set it to `true` initially and don't change it, therefore the code will never enter `if(playing==false){`.

So I would recommend taking out your `if...else` statements altogether, and just run the `do...while` loop and then let it go to the end block to determine who wins and run your print statements etc.

Also, you should remove `System.exit(0)` as this will end the program before you print anything.

I would also just have a counter that adds up who wins each round slightly different to how you have displayed it; for example within the `do...while` just add one to a wins counter.

Here is an [example](https://ideone.com/1GW0SA) of it online.